# Difference between boolean and logical

Tags: matlab, boolean

Out of curiosity, if I type these lines in MATLAB:

```
a = logical([12 0 1.2]);
b = boolean([12 0 1.2]);
```

The output variables `a` and `b` are the same (same value and type). Hence, is there any difference between `boolean` and `logical`?

Comment: Does `boolean` really exist in Matlab? Which Matlab version do you use?

Comment: In R2011b and R2013b, I can execute it. I think the `boolean` is connected to Simulink somehow. BTW, thank you for the reply. This question is not critical, but I was just curious :)

Comment: I see. Yes, it's [related to Simulink](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/simulink/ug/working-with-data-types.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick look at the boolean function can give you a good answer to your question:

If you type : `edit boolean` in the matlab console you get:

```
function y = boolean(x)
%BOOLEAN Creates a boolean vector.
%   This function is typically used in Simulink parameter dialogs, such as
%   the Constant block dialog.  This function generates a logical vector,
%   which is treated as a boolean value in Simulink.  Now that logical is a
%   MATLAB type, this function is essentially just an alias.
%
%   Y = BOOLEAN(X) Converts the vector X into a boolean vector.
%
%   Example: 
%      boolean([0 1 1]) returns [0 1 1]
%
%   See also LOGICAL.

%   Copyright 1990-2012 The MathWorks, Inc.

narginchk(1,1);

if ~isreal(x)
    DAStudio.error('Simulink:utility:BooleanCannotBeComplex');
end

y = logical(x);
```

If you look at the last line of this function, you can see that the boolean function call the logical function.

Comment: not to mention `this function is essentially just an alias` in the description

Answer (score 9):

`logical` is a MATLAB built-in, `boolean` is a Simulink function.

Part of the return from typing `help boolean`:

> This function is typically used in Simulink parameter dialogs, such as
>       the Constant block dialog.  This function generates a logical vector,
>       which is treated as a boolean value in Simulink.  Now that logical is a
>       MATLAB type, this function is essentially just an alias.

If you type `edit boolean` at the command line, you will see that it basically just calls `logical` on the input.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be very clear: There is *no such thing* as a `boolean` data type in MATLAB (at least not anymore).

Explicitly demonstrating what the OP stated:

```
>> a = logical([12 0 1.2]);
>> b = boolean([12 0 1.2]);
>> whos a b
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class      Attributes

  a         1x3                 3  logical              
  b         1x3                 3  logical
```

`boolean` is not a recognized type:

```
>> cast(a,'boolean')
Error using cast
Unsupported class for conversion.
```

As other answers have said, the `boolean` function comes with Simulink and is little more than an alias for a `logical` cast.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is just an alias for logical now since logical is also a MATLAB type. Boolean is still used in Simulink. Infact, boolean in itself just simply calls the function logical.